# Jquery Multiple Draggable and Droppable Items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, cart, droppable

I have a jquery droppable cart which I customised from this code by [Sarath Sprakash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2472111/sarathsprakash) . It allows donors to select from a number of pre-defined donation amounts and drag them onto the category they wish to support and adds them up into a total.

Everything is working fine, except when you drag a draggable out of a droppable. If you have two or more donations of £10 in different droppables and remove one, it also removes the other, although the total adds up correctly.

I suspect it's something to do with the clone but can't trace the problem. Can anyone help?

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mrdh592z/

HTML:

```
<div id="dragAndDrop"><a id="dragtop"></a>&nbsp;
<div id="amounts">
<h2>Please place stickers for the amount you want to give in any or all of these circles to help people move out of homelessness.</h2>
<div class="ui-widget-content" data-value="10" data-count="0">&pound;10</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content" data-value="15" data-count="0">&pound;15</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content" data-value="25" data-count="0">&pound;25</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content" data-value="50" data-count="0">&pound;50</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content" data-value="100" data-count="0">&pound;100</div>
</div>
<div id="categories">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="descriptionWrap">
<div class="description">
<div id="first" class="droppable" data-count="0">&nbsp;</div>
<h3>First Meeting</h3>
<p>Help us be there for more homeless people with a friendly smile, a warming cup of tea and precious time to talk.</p>
</div>
<div class="description">
<div class="droppable" data-count="0">&nbsp;</div>
<h3>Goal Setting</h3>
<p>Give the support many homeless people need to identify positive goals and work towards them, one step at a time.</p>
</div>
<div class="description">
<div class="droppable" data-count="0">&nbsp;</div>
<h3>IT Skills</h3>
<p>Help us provide more classes so that people can learn IT skills to help them build their confidence and find a job.</p>
</div>
<div class="description">
<div class="droppable" data-count="0">&nbsp;</div>
<h3>CV Skills</h3>
<p>Help give more homeless people the training, support and encouragement they need to create good CVs and find employment.</p>
</div>
<div class="description">
<div class="droppable" data-count="0">&nbsp;</div>
<h3>A home of their own</h3>
<p>Provide advice, support and household items to people who are setting up home again after months or years of being homeless.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="totalWrap">
<div id="totalText">Total : &pound;</div>
<div id="counter">0</div>
<div id="reset"><input id="zero" type="button" value="Reset" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
var a = 0;
    var i = 0;
var q = 0;
    var drg;
var z = parseInt($('.droppable').attr('data-count'));

$(function () {
    var cln;
    $(".ui-widget-content").draggable({
        drag: function (event, ui) {
           drg = $(this);
            $(".droppable").droppable('enable');
        },
        helper: 'clone'

    });

    $(".droppable").droppable({
tolerance: "fit",
        drop: function () {
var q = parseInt($('.droppable').children('.runningTotal').html());
            a = a + parseInt(drg.attr('data-value'));
            $("#counter").html(a);
             i++;
             z++;
q=q+parseInt($(drg).attr('data-value'));
           var txt = drg.text() + "1";
                $(this).append("<div class='mini' id=" + drg.text() + " data-value=" + drg.attr('data-value') + ">" + drg.text() + "</div>");
                 q==0;


            $("#" + drg.text()).draggable({
                drag: function (event, ui) {
                    drg = $(this);


                },
                stop: function (event, ui) {
                    var tt = drg.text() + "1";
                     i--;
                    if (parseInt($("#" + tt).text()) > 1) {
                        $("#" + tt).html(parseInt($("#" + tt).text()) - 1);



                    } else {

                        $("#" + drg.text()).remove();

                        $(this).remove();

                    }
                    a = a - parseInt(drg.attr('data-value'));
                    $("#counter").html(a);

                },
                helper: 'clone'
            });
        }

    });
});
$('#zero').click(function() {
$('#PC14234_txtAmount').val(0);
$('.mini').remove();
$('#counter').html('0');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for all same amount getting remove is its ID. Its same for all same amount so .remove(), removes all clone from droppable. So to get rid of this issue, you got to make id unique. Replace your JS code with following JS code:

```
var a = 0;
var i = 0;
var q = 0;
var drg;
var z = parseInt($('.droppable').attr('data-count'));
var cnt=0;//counter variable for unique id

$(function () {
  var cln;
  $(".ui-widget-content").draggable({
    drag: function (event, ui) {
       drg = $(this);
        $(".droppable").droppable('enable');
    },
    helper: 'clone'
 });

$(".droppable").droppable({
    tolerance: "fit",
    drop: function () {
    var q = parseInt($('.droppable').children('.runningTotal').html());
        a = a + parseInt(drg.attr('data-value'));
        $("#counter").html(a);
         i++;
         z++;
    q=q+parseInt($(drg).attr('data-value'));
       var txt = drg.text() + "1";
        cnt=cnt+1;
        var id=cnt+parseInt($(drg).attr('data-value'));//creating unique id by adding cnt value to it.
            $(this).append("<div class='mini' id=" +id + " data-value="     + drg.attr('data-value') + ">" + drg.text() + "</div>");
             q==0;

        $("#" + id).draggable({
            drag: function (event, ui) {
                drg = $(this);
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                var tt = id + "1";
                 i--;
                if (parseInt($("#" + tt).text()) > 1) {
                    $("#" + tt).html(parseInt($("#" + tt).text()) - 1);

                } else {
                    $("#" + id).remove();
                    $(this).remove();
                }
                a = a - parseInt(drg.attr('data-value'));
                $("#counter").html(a);
            },
            helper: 'clone'
        });
    }
  });
});
$('#zero').click(function() {
$('#PC14234_txtAmount').val(0);
$('.mini').remove();
$('#counter').html('0');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Akshay. That has worked perfectly. Could you highlight which line you have edited. is It $('#' + id).remove();

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy - Yes. I have added one new variable with "cnt" name. At the time of drop function have assigned value to this "cnt" variable in 

cnt=cnt+1;
var id=cnt+parseInt($(drg).attr('data-value'));

Then have used this "id" variable for draggable function and at the time of removing dragged element also. I have added comment also in my answer for your reference wherever i have made any changes.